# Could you use Microsoft Print to PDF printer to convert an XPS to a PDF file?

Tags: wpf, pdf, .net-core, printing, xps

I am trying to use the Microsoft Print to PDF printer to convert an XPS to a PDF.

I Tried converting my XPS Files via commandline with GhostReader and also tried to use PdfSharp.Xps. Both of these were too slow, Taking more then 30 seconds for a 10 page XPS file. Now my question is if it is possible to set an input and output File/Path for printing when i use Microsoft print to PDF

```cs
string fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string xpsFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), $"{fileGuid}.Print.xps");
string pdfFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), $"{fileGuid}.Print.pdf");

PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
{
    DocumentName = xpsFile,
                
    PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
    {
            PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",
            PrintToFile = true,
            PrintFileName = pdfFile,
    }
                
};
doc.Print();
```

This is what i have tried. But this creates an empty .PDF file that i can't use

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com) (disclaimer: I am an employee of this vendor) which actually supports loading and saving XPS files in C# so you do not need to use a printer to do the conversion, you can simply do it directly in your application: https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats#document

So you could use the toolkit to simply load an XPS and save it out as a PDF quite easily with the following code and nuget package:

> [Install-Package Leadtools.Document.Sdk -Version 21.0.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Document.Sdk/)

```
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{    
    documentConverter.SetDocumentWriterInstance(new DocumentWriter();

    foreach (var filename in inputFiles)
    {
        var jobData = new DocumentConverterJobData();
        jobData.InputDocumentFileName = "input.xps";
        jobData.DocumentFormat = DocumentFormat.Pdf;
        jobData.OutputDocumentFileName = "output.pdf");

        var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
        documentConverter.Jobs.RunJobAsync(job);
    }
}
```

Here is a complete tutorial on how to achieve this here: https://test.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/documents/cross-platform/dotnet-core/convert-files-with-the-document-converter.html

If you would rather use a printer to do the functionality, there is the Virtual Printer Driver that supports the XPS -> PDF conversion as well:
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/virtual-printer/windows/dotnet/print-to-file-using-the-virtual-printer-driver.html